# Installer: Erase and reinstall on existing ubuntu partition erases all partitions including windows partitions

Tags: installation, 13.04

when trying to install 13.04 in an existing ubuntu partition. the installer gives an option "erase and reinstall on existing  ubuntu partition". doing that also erase all the other partions on that hardrive in including ntfs/fat ones and makes one big partition.

is that a nasty bug or a feature ? this might be reproducible easily in VM.

Comment: This is fairly subjective. I think it is a bug, because every month we get several questions here of people that did not understand it and subsequently panic. So I think it is a usability issue.

Comment: they should add a warning or a short description in the installer. that being said, linux installers are always a bit confusing. for this reason i always do the manual way.

Answer (score 2):

That is a feature - and not a bug.

Depends really on what kind of partitions you've made earlier, and what they are used for. If Ubuntu is the only operating-system used on a computer, it will remove all partitions because it wont affect other OS's.

Comment: Indeed. If you want to preserve data you need to select "manual"

Comment: Thankx. that cleared it. i had two partitions one ext3 and another ntfs (no windows). now i have one ext4 + swap.

Comment: This attitude doesn't help Ubuntu. Of course it's a bug. Why would you take pleasure in someone losing their Windows partition and data? How is that a selling point for Ubuntu?